# Forms software required that mimics ms access but with compacity for large amounts of data

Tags: database, oracle, forms, ms-access

**Updated to be on topic**

I have a problem where Microsoft access is not powerful enough for a migration from oracle forms.  The forms I'm using are developed long ago and are at the point where they need to be migrated to an updated piece of software.  I want to continue to use software that takes the "CURD" approach where the user is essentially making changes to the actual data table but it doesn't save till the user explicitly clicks a save button.  We are trying to keep the coding to a minimum since the Inserts, Updates and Deletes are happening directly in the table.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you thought about Oracle Apex?

Comment: Who would down-vote absolutely normal question? The people really have nothing to do... And yes, the Apex is basically web Forms, or continue using Forms that also can be deployed on the web. I think these are the best choices. Don't know why Oracle basically abandoned Forms instead of making them better.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  I'm not sure we have a licenses currently for Apex.  I'm going to find out hopefully today.  I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I feel Windows Presentation Foundation is the closest to access forms. You still have to do a fair amount of coding to connect to the database.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/

Comment: Thank you afd31.  I'm going to do some research on the WPF.  I have to come up with a pro/con list for the software I find.

Answer (score 1):

"Is there a specific name that it is called where the client layer sits on top of the database layer where the user interacts with the actual date in the table?"

There's two slightly different aspects to that question.

Firstly, the term "client/server" or "two tier" is typically used when there is software on the client machine that communicates directly with a common storage/database system on another machine. They are less popular now, with most applications having a middle layer between the client (often web or mobile) and database. That improves security and makes it easier to manage changes which may cause inconsistencies between a client and database server.

Secondly, the term "CRUD" is typically used for an application that simply does CREATE/READ/UPDATE/DELETE operations on a database object / table.

Those are not fully interchangeable since a client/server program might have a single user operation that affects multiple tables (either through logic in the client program or by invoking stored procedures on the server). Also you can have CRUD forms delivered through an application layer with a separate web/mobile front end. Many languages have frameworks that make it relatively easy to build CRUD pages/applications against a database layer.

Comment: Thank you so much Gary.  That was the term I was looking for.  I do understand how they are not fully interchangeable.  At least this gives me something to look into further.  Thank you